# Computing dynamic bayesian networks using bnstruct

Tags: r, bayesian-networks

I am trying to compute a dynamic Bayesian network (DBN) using **bnstruct** library in R. The data used here for illustartion is seven variables over two time points.

```
Rep_1 <- c(0, 0, 13343.36, 13343.36, 0, 0, 0.00, 5.36, 0, 0.00, 0, 0.4, 0, 4.56)
Rep_2 <- c(0, 0, 10579.92, 10579.92, 0, 0, 5.76, 33.60, 0, 0.00, 0, 0.0, 0, 0.24)
Rep_3 <- c(0, 0, 11256.40, 11256.40, 0, 0, 68.04, 0.00, 0, 0.04, 0, 0.0, 0, 0.00)

expression <- rbind(Rep1, Rep2, Rep3)
colnames(expression) <- c("var1_t1", "var2_t1", "var3_t1", "var4_t1", "var5_t1", "var6_t1", "var7_t1", "var1_t2", "var2_t2", "var3_t2", "var4_t2", "var5_t2", "var6_t2", "var7_t2")
```

Then I created the BNDataset from it

```
dataset <- BNDataset(data = expression,  discreteness = rep(F, ncol(expression)), 
                 variables = colnames(expression), node.sizes = rep(3, ncol(expression)))
```

And finally computing the DBN using *learn.dynamic.network* from bnstruct

```
dbn <- learn.dynamic.network(dataset, num.time.steps = 2)
```

This gives the error

> *Error in h(simpleError(msg, call)) :
> error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'as.matrix': invalid number of intervals*

I tried changing the expression to dataframe and matrix before applying BNDataset but nothing works.

**Thanks in advance!**

Comment: `expression <- cbind(Rep1, Rep2, Rep3)` should probably be `expression <- rbind(Rep_1, Rep_2, Rep_3)` but SO won't let me edit since it's less than 6 characters. Is this what you meant?

Comment: Yes you are correct. I changed that in my question

Answer (score 2):

Package developer here. I cannot reproduce the error, and I've never seen it either. Apparently `simpleError` is a S3 object, while bnstruct uses S4. Maybe you loaded another package containing a method with a conflicting name?

However, in the MWE the learning in bnstruct will fail on the variables for which you have a single value observed, e.g. `var1_t1` or `var2_t1`. If you have a larger dataset with more values it's probably going to be fine, otherwise the easiest thing to do is to remove those variables.

Comment: Thank you and apologies for late response.
With the help from my colleagues I was able to resolve the issue. It was because of cases where the `colSums()` was zero.